# How to cancel a reloading action properly?

Tags: ghost-recon-phantoms

I know shift (switch to run) can do that. But when I'm in cover, I don't want to move.

So is there another proper way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch weapon. The action of switching will cancel out the reloading. Just scroll down and up really quickly and you will stop reloading and be able to shoot again.